# Set multiple filters in react-table using setFilter

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Is it possible to filter for multiple values using setFilter? This filters any instance of '31' in the age column:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFilter("age", "31");
});
```

I have tried adding an array but it doesn't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFilter("age", ["31", "32"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can pass any value including multiple values (array) into **setFilter** setter.
As writen [here](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters):

```js
setFilter: Function(columnId, filterValue) => void
filterValue: any
```

But, we have to make sure that:

1. The **setFilter** setter is retrieved from the table instance by the using of **useTable** and **useFilter** hooks:

```
const {
 ...
 setFilter,
 ...
} = useTable(
 {
   columns,
   data,
 },
 useFilter
);
```

2. The custom filter process the **filterValue** correctly so it will  return the intended result:

```
function multiSelectFilter(rows, columnIds, filterValue) {
  // beware of "31".includes(1) and ["31", "32"].includes(1)
  // this method will return a different value if you passed in a different value data type.
  return filterValue.length === 0
    ? rows
    : rows.filter((row) => filterValue.includes(row.original[columnIds]));
}
```

3. The custom filter is attached into the **columns** object together with its **id**:

```
columns: [
  {
    Header: "Age",
    accessor: "age",
    id: "age",
    filter: multiSelectFilter    // <--- put it here
  },
]
```

Then you can use the filter at your table as follows:

```
  function Table({ columns, data, filteredAges }) {

    const {
      ...
      setFilter,
      ...
    } = useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
      },
      useFilter
    );
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
      if (filteredAges) {
        setFilter("age", filteredAges);
      }
    }, [filteredAges, setFilter]);

    ...

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
```

Here's the example:

[image: Edit competent-galileo-yixnic]